# In practice, should I use k-fold cross-validation or repeated random sub-sampling validation as my default choice of evaluating the model performance?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, monte-carlo, model-evaluation, subsampling

I was wondering if someone can shed some light on which cross-validation method should I, in general, use more often: k-fold cross-validation or repeated random sub-sampling validation.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)), I understood that k-fold cross-validation makes sure to partition the data, that is, that every data point is in the training dataset and in the validation dataset only once. Repeated random sub-sampling validation, on the other hand, allows for some data points to be in training and/or the validation dataset multiple times, as well as some data points not being in the training and/or the validation dataset at all. Basically, in repeated random sub-sampling validation there is no partitioning; there is randomness which picks out the samples.

If someone can explain some common situations where I'd prefer one over the other and why, I'd appreciate it a lot.